# How to search for exact extension with Google & inurl?

Tags: google-search

For example, I need to find the pages, ending with ".html". I'm trying the term `inurl:.php` but it seems to be the same as `inurl:php`. But I need the pages ending with php **with dot** symbol before extension. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with "filetype:php"

Comment: Why the downvote on this? This is exactly the answer!